# Telegram-web for windows is from electronJs but what about mac

Tags: macos, electron, telegram

I know that telegram web for windows operating system is made from electronJs but I recently shifted to macOS and when I used telegram on MacBook using m1 I released that its quite different from windows's one its build like I has been made for phone not for laptop which is quite convenient. Does telegram app for m1 processors made from electronJs or it is made of something else?????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the Telegram main page is a [Github](https://github.com/overtake/TelegramSwift) repository linked.
It is made with Swift Apple's own programming language.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).